# HostListener stopped working after angular upgrader to latest version (Version 15)

Tags: angular

I have recently upgrade the angular version to angular 15. The following code stopped working and I am not getting the `this.ngControl.value`. I am getting it as blank. Let me know if anyone has encountered the same issue

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({ selector: '[TrimText]'})
export class TrimTextDirective {
  constructor(private ngControl: NgControl) {
  }
  @HostListener('input', ['$event']) 
    onInputChange() {
        this.ngControl.control?.setValue(this.ngControl.value.replace(/^\s+/g, '').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,' '));
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't add the parameter to the function `onInputChange(ev: InputEvent)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so after some digging I got the values by doing this

```
@HostListener('input', ['$event.target.value']) 
onInputChange(value: string) {...
```